# Apache POI : Duplicate detection of rows using multiple columns

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am trying to highlight duplicate rows in excel for the subset of columns using java.
I have created a conditional format rule and applied the **COUNTIFS**  formula for identifying duplicates.

The formula works for the first two subset columns **I4:J7**.  If I extend the formula to the next column K7, duplicate- detection is not working.

```
        SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
        
                        // Working
        ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("=COUNTIFS(I$4:I$7,I$4:I$7,J$4:J$7,J$4:J$7)>1");
        
                        // Not Working
        //ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("=COUNTIFS(I$4:I$7,I$4:I$7,J$4:J$7,J$4:J$7,K$4:K$7,\"*\"&K$4:K$7&\"*\")>1");

        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FontFormatting font = rule1.createFontFormatting();          
        font.setFontStyle(false, true);
        font.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);

        CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("I4:I7")};
        sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
```

**Excel**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather an Excel problem than a problem of Apache POI.

The formula `=COUNTIFS(I$4:I$7,I$4:I$7,J$4:J$7,J$4:J$7,K$4:K$7,"*"&K$4:K$7&"*")>1` works in a worksheet of Excel 365 and uses spilling array behavior and automatically spreads over a range of four rows. But it does not work as formula in conditional formatting. I guess this is because of problems using the spilling array behavior while concatenating text using `&` operator.

The same works using following formula `=COUNTIFS(I$4:I$7,I4,J$4:J$7,J4,K$4:K$7,"*"&K4&"*")>1` in one cell and filled down then. There the rows in the references `I4`, `J4` and `K4` count up while filling down because of not using `$` in those references.

This formula also works in conditional formatting. At least using Office Open XML format `*.xlsx`.

So try:

```
ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("COUNTIFS(I$4:I$7,I4,J$4:J$7,J4,K$4:K$7,\"*\"&K4&\"*\")>1");
```

---

If the need is to highlight the duplicates in columns `I:K` instead of only in column `I`, then the conditional formatting needs to be applied to all the columns `I4:K7` instead of only `I4:I7`. But then the formula must also fixate the columns using `$` too: `COUNTIFS($I$4:$I$7,$I4,$J$4:$J$7,$J4,$K$4:$K$7,"*"&$K4&"*")>1`.  Else the column letters would count up for columns right from the first one.

```
...
ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("COUNTIFS($I$4:$I$7,$I4,$J$4:$J$7,$J4,$K$4:$K$7,\"*\"&$K4&\"*\")>1");
...
CellRangeAddress[] regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("I4:K7")};
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Axel it really worked :). I am trying to highlight the blue font styling for the entire  duplicate rows. Only first column is getting highlighted . Did I missed anything ?

Comment: You apply the CF to `I4:I7` only. See supplements in my answer,